# How to build app via XCode 10 and Cordova?

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, macos-high-sierra

I have macOS High Sierra and I am trying build app for IOS via Cordova `cordova build ios`, but I get next error `xcodebuild requires Xcode, but active develeoper directory ... is a command line tools instance`

What I have installed?
Node Js, Cordova, XCode 10, ios-deploy, cocoapods

Comment: Why don't you update your Xcode? Xcode 10 is an ancient version.

Comment: I dont have opportunity)

Comment: Just press the Update button.